# lodash find object by id across an entire nested object

Tags: lodash

I would like to find **name** value at whatever level when searching by **ID**

I assume Lodash would be the best method, I have been searching and testing but no luck, is this possible?

```
{
  "delegate": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "David",
      "balances": [],
      "responsibility": [
        {
          "id": "18",
          "name": "Lilly",
          "balances": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Barb",
      "balances": [],
      "responsibility": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Amy",
          "balances": []
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "name": "John",
          "balances": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responsibility": [
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Shawn",
      "balances": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is your `id` unique across all items?

Comment: good point, yes it is - thx